# Google App Engine Barrier Synchronization

Tags: google-app-engine

I have n parallel tasks running. When all these tasks are done, I want to create another task. What is the best way to do this ? Since a datastore operation is slower, I used memcache. I keep incrementing the counter by 1 when each task is finished. I keep checking the counter for n. Since memcache is not reliable, the counter value is lost sometimes. Any other solutions?

Comment: "Since memcache is not reliable" - huh? Have you considerd it might actually be your code at fault?

Comment: @Mitch: I think Sam is referring to the fact that memcache may evict any entry at any time - and thus is not well-suited to storing a value which you can't afford to lose (as in the scheme Sam described above).

Comment: @ David Underhill: OK, good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't afford to lose your counter, you need to use the datastore to ensure that your counter isn't lost (e.g., due to an unexpected memcache eviction).  However, you could *also* store the value in memcache - that way you can still get fast reads of the counter from memcache (and go to the datastore to get the count if the memcache entry has expired).

If you have so many tasks running in parallel that incrementing the datastore counter is too slow, then consider using a [sharded counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) to relieve this bottleneck.

Comment: i agree with David, in GAE memcache there are atomic operation for this cases, this counter https://github.com/gregbayer/gae-livecount uses memcahe with the datastore to save the value in a separate task, i use it and it works really good. i'm going to give sharding counters a try.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend use the [appengine-pipeline](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline)

Intenally it implements a barrier with models.